# Same Date... But Different? Maybe timezone confusion

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

**My problem** is that I save a date into a string and as a date in CoreData. Later, I need to pull the date out of the string, compare the two, and find that they're the same date. Right now, that equality check fails. The two dates are 7 hours apart but with the minutes correct. I think it's a timezone issue but I can't figure out how to solve it.

**The Origin of the Dates**

I have a date from a date picker that I save to CoreData like this:

```
task.setValue(dueDatePicker.date, forKey: "dueDate")
```

After that I format the date and insert that date into a message:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let dateFormat = DateFormatter.Style.medium
let timeFormat = DateFormatter.Style.short
dateFormatter.dateStyle = dateFormat     
dateFormatter.timeStyle = timeFormat
let formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
let message = ("Upcoming task on \(formattedDate)")
```

That message becomes part of a notification. Hours or days later (when the notification fires and the user selects an action) I get the CoreData date:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dueDate = %@", dateOfTask)
```

Then I decompose the notification message and get the date:

```
let start = notifString.range(of: "on ")
let rawDate = notifString[(start.upperBound)!..<(notifString.endIndex)]
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone =
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM-d-yyyy, H:mm a"
let dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: rawDate)
```

Lastly, I compare them. Currently the times are clearly the same day and minute but the timezones differ by about 7 hours. However, I don't want to just force a timezone that matches (Maybe force UTC for example) because that may not work for a user in another location.

How do I retrieve both dates without getting this apparent timezone issue?

Comment: I did see similar code like "dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")". So you did not give a timezone.

Comment: I don't completely understand. Are these local notifications or push notifications? If they're push notifications then how are you generating a date string that makes sense for the user, given that they might be in a different time zone? If they're local notifications then can't you assme that the date string from the notification is in the user's current time zone and set the time zone on the date formatter accordingly?

Comment: If the data is coming from a UILocalNotificstion then you should store the relevant data in the `userInfo` dictionary rather than trying to parse the string

Comment: Please add print statements (and their output) which clearly show *what* you are comparing.

Comment: @Paulw11 Using userInfo worked. Thanks, the dates now match. I hadn't used it before and thought it was for something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blatantly obvious, use userInfo as @Paulw11 suggested:

```
    newLocalNotif.fireDate = dueDateWarningTime
    newLocalNotif.alertBody = message
    newLocalNotif.timeZone = TimeZone.autoupdatingCurrent
    newLocalNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    newLocalNotif.category = "DueDates"
    newLocalNotif.userInfo = ["name": name, "desc": desc, "dueDate" : date]
```